# Digits in float and double variable

Tags: c++, floating-point, double

Why is the number of digits stored by both float as well as double variable same, isn't double supposed to store more digits than float

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
double a = 3.141528579238;
float b = 3.141528579238; 
cout << a << " " << b;
return 0;
}
```

I'm getting this as my output

```
3.14153 3.14153
```

Comment: The number of digits stored is not the same as the number of digits displayed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: @OP:  For you to make any observations about what is stored, you need to inspect the numbers in the debugger / memory, not use output statements to display the number.

Comment: doubles and floats are storing _binary_ digits rather than decimal ones. And yes, double have more of those.

Comment: Also, any reason why you are using this particular number, so close to π?

Comment: No particular reason actually..just started with 3.1415 and just typed random numbers after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are facing is because first you should know that float has 4 bytes and double has 8 bytes and 3.141528579238 maybe can be stored in both and if you want to show more digits i suggest first including:
`#include <iomanip>` then you can use the following to print any amount of digits after the "." : `cout << std::setprecision(7) << myFloat;` this will display 3.1415285.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't about digits it's about bits!

`float`s are `32bit` and `double`s are `64bit`.
A floating point number can be expressed like this: `a*2^x` where `a < 1` and `a => 0`.
`a` and `x` will be stored in either `32- or 64-bit` memory.

The reason why your program is printing the same thing is because it just doesn't print your whole number.